# Int type conversion

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion

1) How do you convert from one `Int` type to a `Num` type?

Similar questions have been asked before and the answer has been (as is on the Haskell wiki) is to use `fromIntegral`. `fromIntegral` returns a `Num` type so I have to cast this to my desired format.

I need to take a `Word16` and convert it to a `Int64` so I am doing the following

```
let valueLength = (fromIntegral(tagLength) :: Int64)
```

where `tagLength` has type `Word16`

Is this approach correct?

2) How do you handle type conversion safely?

Coming from a Java background where there is for Integers I believe `Short`,`Int` and `Long`
I can use a `short` as an `int` but not the other way around. In Haskell though if I write

```
256 :: Word8
```

in `ghci` it returns 0.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I need to take a Word16 and convert it to a Int64 so I am doing the following:
>
> ```
> let valueLength = (fromIntegral(tagLength) :: Int64)
> ```
>
> Is this approach correct?

Let's ask GHC!

```
Prelude Data.Word Data.Int> :t fromIntegral :: Word16 -> Int64
fromIntegral :: Word16 -> Int64 :: Word16 -> Int64
```

Looks good.

> How do you handle type conversion safely?

Haskell does not have type conversion. At all. All "conversions" must be done by writing a function that "converts" from one type to another.

> If I write `256 :: Word8` in `ghci` it returns `0`.

Number literals are polymorphic. For things with no decimal point, `fromInteger` is used implicitly:

```
Prelude> :t 256
256 :: Num a => a
Prelude> :t fromInteger
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
Prelude> fromInteger (256 :: Integer) :: Word8
0
```

It might be nice if there was a warning or something for numeric literals with a monomorphic type that were out of range for that type; perhaps you should file a feature request on GHC's bug tracker.